# Filling a 5x5x5 grid

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, wordplay, three-dimensional

Inspired by [this](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/65130405#65130405). On each line to the left is the position of a word, and to the right is the "snyptic clue" **not a cryptic clue (duh)** for the word, along with the word's length. The 5x5x5 cube should be uniquely filled with letters. Maybe I'll add the specific rules as to how the position encoding works and what a snyptic clue actually is, but hopefully the geniuses of PSE can figure it out themselves! Oh, and did I mention an extra twist?

should i do a 10x10x10 lol

```
413-00: FBYVYBONVGR (4)
153+-0: RZREHCGVBAQ (5)
2110+0: SSCRAMBLELIK (4)
515-+0: QVFZHEZHEYR (5)
32200+: CHROMOSOMERIC (4)
112+00: LECTUREERS (5)
53100+: SDISTRACTING (5)
155+00: MATCHESOMELY (5)
215++0: CONSHELTERSE (4)
153+00: QRFCBHFRQ (5)
532-00: SENTIENTROOMS (4)
3450-0: RUBESIDESIUM (4)
3550--: MANGIFERALD (5)
111+00: ENTIRETYSALE (5)
515-+-: IVGVFYVXR (5)
522-+0: EXTRACTOVER (4)
123++0: ARPRFFVGLYR (4)
234+00: SPUPPETING (4)
1220+0: SORARGUMENTS (4)
114++0: UPEMPIRERS (5)
143+00: FCBGYRFFFR (5)
1150+0: TENCRCEBQHPG (5)
154+00: PLPSNVYHERVAR (5)
2120+0: SEASEGMENT (5)
141+00: GPUNEVGLSHY (4)
511-+0: OIVYYNVAEL (5)
114+00: MISEPTENARYTS (5)
1110++: INCORRECTDOER (5)
41500-: BIEXECUTEISM (5)
122+00: FDEXTRALFUL (5)
44200+: TNORQYNZZNA (4)
551-00: NAGVFCNEXYR (5)
1110+0: CLOCKBRIGHT (4)
2150+0: CHORFACTS (4)
34400-: RAFHVATQBBE (4)
133+00: BSSFHECNFF (4)
551--+: CONBIVOUACS (5)
552-00: NAMINUTESLAS (5)
1140+0: NSPBAPYHFVIR (5)
5220+0: DUPLICATEIGHT (4)
144+00: BEINGENIOUSH (4)
211++0: REPERCEIVESED (4)
112++0: COQUETTEIAN (5)
423-00: NARECURSIVEG (4)
5210+0: SCAMPERER (4)
52500-: COPYSOUTH (4)
54400-: CANDIDYLAND (4)
```

Update on position encodings:

> The first three numbers signify the starting position of the word $(x,y,z)$, and the next three signifies the direction the word goes, where $+$ means incrementing in that direction, $-$ means decrementing in that direction, and $0$ means no change in that direction.

And here's an example of a snyptic clue:

> INTELLIGENTIE (5) - SMART

(If it isn't enough I'll update with more examples...)

**Partial answers are welcome.**

Comment: Looks more like a groceries receipt than a fun puzzle

Comment: tbh crosswords looks like groceries as well lol

Comment: Are you missing an R in the fifth-to-last clue?

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan No, but can you elaborate on why you think so?

Comment: Because it looks to me as if rot13(n pyhr vf S(k) jurer k pyhrf l, gur nafjre, naq S(l) vf nyfb n jbeq; naq guvf pnfr ybbxf yvxr S = "nccraq VTUG" naq [nafjre]+EVTUG vf n jbeq jurernf [nafjre]+VTUG vf abg). But of course I may be misunderstanding and I do see other clues that look like rot13(n yrggre vf zvffvat) so probably there's a general pattern I'm not quite grasping yet.

Comment: Actually, it looks as if rot13(gur rot13ed ones are just gratuitously rot13ed, rather than having the property that insert+rot13 yields a word) so my attempt at rot13(trarenyvmngvba) seems to have been overoptimistic.

Comment: I also seem to have a clash between `1110++` and `133+00`, both of whose solutions seem pretty clear-cut. As always, the error is probably mine.

Comment: I am pretty sure your individual solutions are fine, you just need to figure out the twist.

Comment: Can `154-00` really be correct? (I guess it _could_ be wrapping, but none of the others I've looked at so far need to wrap.)

Comment: I think I messed up some directions, which I'm fixing... in particular that `-` should be `+`.

Comment: (I have figured out one thing I was doing wrong elsewhere.)

Comment: The directions have be fixed and double checked.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151356/discussion-between-sny-smartie-and-gareth-mccaughan).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How the clues work:

> they have the form XYZ where X or Z may be empty, with Y an approximate synonym for the answer and X[answer]Z also being a word

except that

> sometimes the whole thing is ROT13ed meaning that the answer needs to be ROT13ed before entry.

Solutions:

> ```
> 413-00: FBYVYBONVGR (4) SOLILOBAITE -> QUIZ (soliloquize) -> DHVM
> 153+-0: RZREHCGVBAQ (5) EMERUPTIOND -> BLAZE (emblazed) -> OYNMR
> 2110+0: SSCRAMBLELIK (4) HASH (shashlik)
> 515-+0: QVFZHEZHEYR (5) DISMURMURLE -> GRUNT (disgruntle) -> TEHAG
> 32200+: CHROMOSOMERIC (4) GENE (generic)
> 112+00: LECTUREERS (5) SPEAK (speakers)
> 53100+: SDISTRACTING (5) AWING (sawing)
> 155+00: MATCHESOMELY (5) GAMES (gamesomely)
> 215++0: CONSHELTERSE (4) DENS (condense)
> 153+00: QRFCBHFRQ (5) DESPOUSED -> BRIDE (debrided) -> OEUQR
> 532-00: SENTIENTROOMS (4) WARE (warerooms)
> 3450-0: RUBESIDESIUM (4) THEN (ruthenium)
> 3550--: MANGIFERALD (5) MANGO (mangold)
> 111+00: ENTIRETYSALE (5) WHOLE (wholesale)
> 515-+-: IVGVFYVXR (5) VITISLIKE -> GRAPE (grapelike) -> TENCR
> 522-+0: EXTRACTOVER (4) TAKE (takeover)
> 123++0: ARPRFFVGLYR (4) NECESSITYLE -> NEED (needle) -> ARRQ
> 234+00: SPUPPETING (4) PAWN (spawning)
> 1220+0: SORARGUMENTS (4) ROWS (sorrows)
> 114++0: UPEMPIRERS (5) STATE (upstaters)
> 143+00: FCBGYRFFFR (5) SPOTLESSSE -> CLEAN (cleanse) -> PYRNA
> 1150+0: TENCRCEBQHPG (5) GRAPEPRODUCT -> FRUIT (grapefruit) -> SEHVG
> 154+00: PLPSNVYHERVAR (5) CYCFAILUREINE -> LOSER (cycloserine) -> YBFRE
> 2120+0: SEASEGMENT (5) PIECE (seapiece)
> 141+00: GPUNEVGLSHY (4) TCHARITYFUL -> RUTH (truthful) -> EHGU
> 511-+0: OIVYYNVAEL (5) BVILLAINRY -> ROGUE (broguery) -> EBTHR
> 114+00: MISEPTENARYTS (5) SEVEN (misevents, bleh)
> 1110++: INCORRECTDOER (5) WRONG (wrongdoer)
> 41500-: BIEXECUTEISM (5) PEDAL? (bipedalism)
> 122+00: FDEXTRALFUL (5) RIGHT (frightful)
> 44200+: TNORQYNZZNA (4) GABEDLAMMAN -> RAGE (garageman) -> ENTR
> 551-00: NAGVFCNEXYR (5) ANTISPARKLE -> GLARE (antiglare) -> TXNER
> 1110+0: CLOCKBRIGHT (4) WISE (clockwise)
> 2150+0: CHORFACTS (4) DATA (Chordata)
> 34400-: RAFHVATQBBE (4) ENSUINGDOOR -> NEXT (nextdoor) -> ARKG
> 133+00: BSSFHECNFF (4) OFFSURPASS -> BEAT (offbeat) -> ORNG
> 551--+: CONBIVOUACS (5) TENTS (contents)
> 552-00: NAMINUTESLAS (5) NOTES (nanoteslas)
> 1140+0: NSPBAPYHFVIR (5) AFCONCLUSIVE -> FINAL (affinal) -> SVANY
> 5220+0: DUPLICATEIGHT (4) TWIN (twinight)
> 144+00: BEINGENIOUSH (4) NEAT (beneath)
> 211++0: REPERCEIVESED (4) HEAR (rehearsed)
> 112++0: COQUETTEIAN (5) SIREN (sirenian)
> 423-00: NARECURSIVEG (4) META (nametag)
> 5210+0: SCAMPERER (4) DART (darter)
> 52500-: COPYSOUTH (4) LEFT (copyleft)
> 54400-: CANDIDYLAND (4) FAIR (fairyland)
> ```

I have a number of quibbles:

> several of the definitions seem pretty dicey to me (pedal = execute? siren = coquette? bedlam = rage? chromosome = gene? Mangifera = mango?), some of the words-after-insertion are also fairly iffy and/or very obscure (affinal, seapiece, twinight, gamesomely).

Anyway, with all those I get this grid:

> ```
> plane 1
>     W I S E R
>     S R O W S
>     M A O P O
>     S V A N Y
>     S E H V G
>
> plane 2
>     H A S H E
>     P I E C E
>     V T R Y E
>     E T P E B
>     D A T A A
>
> plane 3
>     O E T G N
>     E G R K T
>     H E N R U
>     V N A A F
>     N E H T M
>
> plane 4
>     L B A U X
>     A H A E O
>     D M G N Q
>     E E W T R
>     P E N R E
>
> plane 5
>     E D A R T
>     K T W I N
>     R F I A R
>     N E N F E
>     T L G S S
> ```

Comment: 143+00: FCBGYRFFFR (5) SPOTLESSE -> CLEAN (cleane) -> PYRNA

You missed an F/S there, but I do seem to have missed two clues for plane 5

also you forgot to put "RUTH/EHGU" in

Comment: oh, good catch on the missing F/S. (And, therefore, my apologies for complaining about "CLEANE"!)

Comment: I definitely didn't forget to put EHGU in. (I wrote a little Python script to put everything into the grid because I was making so many mistakes doing it by hand. I can see EHGU right there in what I fed into it.)

Comment: (And all the letters are there in the grid.)

Answer (score 1):

## Puzzle Explanation

Here's the solution for the puzzle:

```
W I S E R        S R O W S        M A O P O        S V A N Y        S E H V G
H A S H E        P I E C E        V T R Y E        E T P E B        D A T A A
O E T G N        E G R K T        H E N R V        V N A A F        N E H T M
L B A U Y        A H A E O        D M G N Q        E E W T R        P E N R E
E D A R T        K T W I N        R F I A R        N E N F E        T L G S S

ROT13:

J V F R E        F E B J F        Z N B C B        F I N A L        F R U I T
U N F U R        C V R P R        I G E L R        R G C R O        Q N G N N
B R G T A        R T E X G        U R A E I        I A N N S        A R U G Z
Y O N H L        N U N R B        Q Z T A D        R R J G E        C R A E R
R Q N E G        X G J V A        E S V N E        A R A Z R        G Y T F F
```

```
. 5210+0: SCAMPERer (4) - DART
. 52500-: copySOUTH (4) - LEFT
. 54400-: CANDIDyland (4) - FAIR
. 111+00: ENTIRETYsale (5) - WHOLE
. 1110++: INCORRECTdoer (5) - WRONG
. 551--+: conBIVOUACS (5) - TENTS
. 53100+: sDISTRACTING (5) - AWING
. 211++0: rePERCEIVEsed (4) - HEAR
. 1110+0: clockBRIGHT (4) - WISE
. 2110+0: sSCRAMBLElik (4) - HASH
. 1220+0: sorARGUMENTS (4) - ROWS
. 2120+0: seaSEGMENT (5) - PIECE
. 122+00: bDEXTRALful (5) - RIGHT
. 112+00: LECTUREers (5) - SPEAK
. 112++0: COQUETTEian (5) - SIREN
. 5220+0: DUPLICATEight (4) - TWIN
. 522-+0: EXTRACTover (4) - TAKE
. 532-00: SENTIENTrooms (4) - WARE
. 32200+: CHROMOSOMEric (4) - GENE
. 552-00: naMINUTESlas (5) - NOTES
. 423-00: naRECURSIVEg (4) - META
. 144+00: beINGENIOUSh (4) - NEAT
. 114++0: upEMPIRErs (5) - STATE
. 114+00: miSEPTENARYts (5) - SEVEN
. 234-00: sPUPPETing (4) - PAWN
. 41500-: biEXECUTEism (5) - PEDAL
. 3550--: MANGIFERAld (5) - MANGO
. 155+00: MATCHESomely (5) - GAMES
. 3450-0: ruBESIDESium (4) - THEN
. 215++0: conSHELTERSe (4) - DENS
. 2150+0: chorFACTS (4) - DATA
! 511+-0: bVILLAINry (5) - ROGUE
! 551-00: antiSPARKLE (5) - GLARE
! 141+00: tCHARITYful (4) - RUTH
! 44200+: gaBEDLAMman (4) - RAGE
! 133+00: offSURPASS (4) - BEAT
! 413-00: soliloBAITe (4) - QUIZ
! 123++0: NECESSITYle (4) - NEED
! 153+-0: emERUPTIONd (5) - BLAZE
! 143+00: SPOTLESSse (5) - CLEAN
! 153+00: deSPOUSEd (5) - BRIDE
! 1140+0: afCONCLUSIVE (5) - FINAL
! 34400-: ENSUINGdoor (4) - NEXT
! 154-00: cycFAILUREine (5) - LOSER
! 515-+-: VITISlike (5) - GRAPE
! 515-+0: disMURMURle (5) - GRUNT
! 1150+0: grapePRODUCT (5) - FRUIT
```

(where `!`  indicates that the clue has been encoded in ROT-13)

The "snyptic clue" takes inspiration from cryptic clues, since
it has a definition part and a "wordplay" part, although the
"wordplay" part is different from cryptic clues in that they clue
a **different** word. I was inspired to make a 3D puzzle by
[this](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/65130405#65130405)
although it is too much work and I will probably stick to 2D puzzles.

I thought of the ROT-13 since I wanted something easily reversible
such that I can work on two sets of clues at the same time.
It also needed to be what encoded the clues and ROT-13 was much
more obvious than, say, a matrix transposition cipher, to spot.